# Silverlight run web-server when executing via HTML file

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I've created a Silverlight application using VS 2012 (SL 5). When I run it in Visual Studio, everything works perfectly, and a web-server is executed alongside my app. But when I run HTML file generated by Visual Studio, no web-server is run and therefore some features of my application (for instance Telerik RadUpload) stop working. What is going wrong? My end-users should be able to run app by clicking this HTML file. How can I run a web-server alongside my app when HTML file is clicked?

Comment: You need to put the HTML file on a running web server. The web server you get from Visual Studio is a developer web server that is used for debugging.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do it? how can I get a running server? is there any sample code or tutorial?

Comment: It depends on how and where you want to run this. The simplest way to do this is to get a web hotel cheap somewhere on the web. Just make sure that it is running MS IIS With .NET. The cheapest hotels often supports open source only, such as Linux with PHP. If you set this up locally you should have a Windows that is NOT home edition or something like this. You should then be able to go to the control panel and turn on IIS on the machine. A search for this will quickly show you how.

Comment: OK thanks, but how can I run server on local host? My users run html file from their own computers, i.e. there is no internet, is there any option?

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea for a solution to this. You should be able to run the Silverlight file locally, but some of the functionality will be Limited. For instance is permission to the local file system, printing etc. VERY strict. These limitation can be handled if you put this on a server and sign the files with a certificate and install the application as Out-Of-Browser (OOB). I don't know the details of the Telerik Control, but the Challenges you have might have to do with restricted Access to the file system.

Comment: I also would like to add to my last comment that when you are running your SL application in VS, the development server will run with all permissions so this can give you the wrong picture of how this runs for the end-users.